# Access all available ViewComponents as a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to search through a list of all available ViewComponents in a asp.net core MVC (mvc6?) project, something like this.

Default.cshtml for ViewComponent

```
 foreach (var section in Model.sections)
{
    var sectionId = section.Id;
    if (_siteSettings.AvailableComponents.Any(c => c == sectionId))
    {
        @await Component.InvokeAsync(sectionId);
    }
    else
    {
        <p>Could not find component: @sectionId </p>            
    }        
}
```

Now, I have managed to do this by manually registering each component in a list that is available at runtime. But what I would like to accomplish is to register each view component simply in each component class file, like this:

```
public class NewsList : ViewComponent
{

    private ISiteSettings _siteSettings;
    private string ComponentName = "NewsList";

    public NewsList(ISiteSettings siteSettings)
    {
        _siteSettings = siteSettings;

        _siteSettings.AvailableComponents.Add(ComponentName);
    }


    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {            
        return View();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the constructor of each viewcomponent will not be executed until the viewcomponent is rendered, I need all components to be registered "automatically" somehow. Is that possible?

Comment: Dont know if there is any way to list all the classes that subClass ViewComponent (provided you are creating view components by inheriting from ViewComponent in your project). May at middleware level you can get the list of those view components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to use reflection.  Using `Assembly`, you can get all the Types in your project, and then filter where the `BaseType` is `typeof(ViewComponent)`.

```
var listOfViewComponents = Assembly
                            .GetEntryAssembly()
                            .GetTypes()
                            .Where(x => x.GetTypeInfo().BaseType == typeof(ViewComponent));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Beautiful, works like a charm! I had reflection in mind but I thought that perhaps there was some built in way for ViewComponents.